# QMainWindow Install Event Filter

Tags: qt, events, event-handling, qmainwindow

I am trying to learn how to install an event filter on QMainWindow so that any QDialog that pops up in QMainWindow, the event filter can handle the dialog and center the dialog to the screen.

```
makVrv::DtDeMainWindow& mw = makVrv::DtDeMainWindowProvider::instance(de).igMainWindow();
makVrv::DtQtDeMainWindow *mainW = dynamic_cast<makVrv::DtQtDeMainWindow*>(&mw);

if(mainW)
{
    …
    mainW->installEventFilter(mainW);
}

bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    // how do I get the pointer to the dialog so I can try to center the widget?
}
```

Can anyone please advise how I go about installing the event filter to detect for QDialog so I can center the dialog on the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: `mainW->installEventFilter(mainW);` you are installing event filter on self. If you really want to handle events that come to your mainW, you need to override `QObject::event` method instead.

Second: there are a lot of ways, how to share pointers between classes. It is a basic of OOP. In your case, you need to declare a pointer to dialog as a member of your class and do a check:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if ( obj == dlg ) // Where `dlg` is a pointer to your dialog
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    //...
}
```